# Pass decoded JSON to the view with Phoenix

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using `HTTPoison` and `Poison` to decode a json response to the view. I'm successful decoding the response body, but I'm struggling to get it to the view. I'm getting this error: `cannot encode maps inside lists when the map has 0 or more than 1 elements`

Here is what I'm doing in the controller:

```
url = "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2016/11/06/schedule.json?api_key={api_key}"

case HTTPoison.get(url) do
  {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    decoded_json = Poison.decode!(body)
    redirect(conn, to: schedule_path(conn, :index, decoded_json))
  {:ok, %{status_code: 404}} ->
end
```

Can I pass the response to the redirect like that? I feel that it is the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: You can pass the JSON as a GET argument but it's probably not a good idea. Why don't you just call your view function directly instead of redirecting to another page?

Comment: yeah, that seems like a strange way of doing things...

Comment: @Dogbert Any chance you can point me towards in example of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should probably render the data/view you want instead of redirecting to another controller with your data.

Redirects usually are for something like, after performing an action, like maybe a successful POST request and doing something with the data in the request, you get redirected to another page. They are not generally used to send data from one controller method to another.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish so my example can only be as good as my assumptions. However, here is one way to do it that probably makes a bit more sense than what you are trying to do. I hope that it should at least help you go in a better direction:

```ex
defmodule MyAppWeb.MyController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  alias MyApp.MyScheduleThing

  action_fallback MyAppWeb.FallbackController

  def index(conn, %{"date" => date} = params) do
    with {:ok, schedule} <- MyScheduleThing.get_schedule(date) do
      render(conn, "schedule.html", schedule: schedule)
    end
  end
end
```

And your module for doing whatever

```ex
defmodule MyApp.MyScheduleThing do
  @moduledoc """
  A module in another file to do your HTTP fetching.
  """

  @doc "Do your thing"
  def get_schedule(date) do
    url = url_from_date(date)

    case HTTPoison.get(url) do
    {:ok, %{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
      {:ok, Poison.decode!(body)}
    {:ok, %{status_code: 404}} ->
      {:error, :not_found}
    {:error, _err} ->
      {:error, :internal_server_error}
    end
  end

  defp url_from_date(date) do
    "https://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/#{date}/schedule"
  end
end
```

The `:internal_server_error` return might not be what you want there, so think of it as a placeholder I put without knowledge of your app or intentions.

The `{:error, :not_found}` should actually cause it to hit the fallback controller, when the `with` statement doesn't match. [The default one matches on that](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/d8f0ab2fef786925c1606c98ca334b34126f6f5f/priv/templates/phx.gen.json/fallback_controller.ex#L16). You can add more methods to match in your own fallback controller to suit your needs.

None of this is probably what you really want (as I said, I don't know what you're doing), but should at least help put you somewhat in a better direction with controllers.